# Images not showing for Default Attributes Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have two attributes sets "Default" and "bibliografi". I have another attribute for images as "att_eby_images" . In the website, images does show for products under "bibliografi" but it is not showing under "Default" attribute set. The att_eby_image is there in the "images" tab in the admin.

Dont know where I am going wrong, please help

Comment: Can you check the url and go to that folder where image is stored when uploaded from backend, check permissions of images and related folders.

Comment: hi, I am able to see the images when I paste in in the url, but not showing on the website.  Please can you tell me what permissions should I give for images as well The url is http://www.hardyart.co.uk/AllPrintImages/large/FAR522.jpg and in the attribute as well

Comment: If images are visible individually  then i don't think there is a premission issue. Still you can try giving chmod 775 image.jpg.

Comment: Also check if there are any exttensions installed like adblock in your browser which can cause the issue. Best way to check is try different browser

Comment: I have changed to 775 for that image but still it is not showing in the results page,  what else can be wrong